# PHP Function to create div which will be called x amount of times

Tags: php, html

I am attempting to make an html element that contains `x` amount of other `div`s created by a function where `x` is dependent on the number of elements `$allposts` contains.

```
<div id="postings">
    <?php
    foreach($allposts as $key => $value){
        createPost($key, $value);
    }
    ?>
 </div>
```

This html and php code above is my attempt to create a "posting" for each item that is found in the `$allposts` array.

```
<?php
    function createPost($author, $input)
    {
        $data = [];
        $i = 0;
        foreach($input as $key => $value){
            $data[$i] = $value;
            $i++;
        }
        echo "<div>
                <span class='post-title'>$data[0]</span>
                <span class='post-author'>$author</span>
                <span class='post-date'>$data[1]</span>
                <p class='post-desc'>$data[2]</span>
            </div>";
     }
?>
```

This is the php document that contains the function `createPost($author, $input)`.

The function works but it seems that each time the function is being called, the previous post is overridden leaving only one post visible which ends up being the last one in the array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Get the `$data` array declaration outside of `foreach` and the other change needs to be done is, do not use $i as key of $data array because everytime, it will be declared with 0 (zero) and so, all new values replace the previos one. So instead of using `$i` keep it `$data[]` so it will automatically add numeric indexes.

```
<?php
    $data = [];    // I took it out of the loop.
    function createPost($author, $input)
    {
        foreach($input as $key => $value){
        $data[] = $value;
    }
    echo "<div>
                <span class='post-title'>$data[0]</span>
                <span class='post-author'>$author</span>
                <span class='post-date'>$data[1]</span>
                <p class='post-desc'>$data[2]</span>
           </div>";
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<p class='post-desc'>$data[2]</span>;
```

does not have the correct closing tag, maybe it is interfering with the formatting resulting in missing data upon rendering to the browser. Do you have a sample of the html source it puts out?
Indentation really helps with readability.

```
<?php

function createPost($author, $input)
{
    $data = [];
    $i = 0;

    foreach($input as $key => $value) {
        $data[$i] = $value;
        $i++;
    }

    echo "<div>
            <span class='post-title'>$data[0]</span>
            <span class='post-author'>$author</span>
            <span class='post-date'>$data[1]</span>
            <p class='post-desc'>$data[2]</p>
          </div>";
}

?>
```